# How to clearfix 2 column post without markup?

Tags: css

I create box post two coloumn six post. When post content not equal The next post box can not float on left. I try to add clearfix class on every two box. But can not fix this issue. I try to create clearfix element  after box two the float working. Finally, I want to clearfix without markup.
Issue Picture :

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

This solution it working But i want to fix without markup.

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <article>
            <figure>
                <a href="" title=""><img src="picture.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </figure>
            <h3><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h3>
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Are you able to use jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Alien's answer works to clear floated elements within a container (you can also use 'overflow: hidden' on the containing element), however your issue is based on different height floated elements (based on the length of text) not stacking as you would expect.

Here are a couple of solutions you could use:

Set the height on each of the floated elements. If they are all the same height, then you won't run into any clearing issues, however you may have clipped text. This solution is best if you know that the image and text will never be above a certain size.

```
.col-xs-6 {
    height: 150px; /* or an arbitrary number you need */
}
```

You could also use the nth-child CSS selector 2n+1 to target every other element, starting from the third one, and clear its floats.

```
.col-xs-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

In both of these cases I would recommend adding a different class to the elements for styling, directly applying styles to bootstrap grids is not recommended, best to separate structure from presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution via jquery if you are able to use jquery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.row .col-xs-6:odd').each(function(index, element) {
        var ele = $(element);
        $('<div class="clearfix"></div>').insertAfter(ele);
    });
});
</script>
```